# Помогите с решением задания на C

Tags: c

[image: задание]

код у мен такой

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int d,c=5;
    float a=5.0,b;
    printf("b = ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("d = ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    a+=b-2;
    d+=++c-a;
    a*=c--;
    a/=10;
    c/=2;
    b--;
    d*=c+b+a;
    printf("RES = %f, %f, %d, %d", &a,&b,&c,&d);
    return 0;
}
```

при выводе выдает НИЧЕГО

Comment: Простите, а вы *вводите* числа? Потому что другой причины не выводить ничего не вижу. Другое дело, что вы пытаетесь вывести **адреса** переменных, а не их значения, но они все равно выводятся... См. https://ideone.com/WByx0f Кстати, выводить значения вас в условии просят *после вычисления **каждого** выражения*...

Comment: Кстати, код у вас вполне приличный, кроме последнего выражения, которое я бы записал как `d *= (c = c/2) + --b + (a = a/10);`